# how to subtract value from grand total in jasper reports using netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, report

I have one application which generates a bill at final using jasper report, now user want to give discount or even there may be advance taken already, so how subtract these values from jasper reports total.

I am retrieving report values from database, everything is working fine but just want subtract 2 values,

prompt box will be okay, or can we access textfield value in jasper report?

Comment: You can add new parameters to the Jasper report, one for discount, one for the advance payment. And then you can integrate these values into your report, subtract the values from the grand total.

Comment: how to add these parameters? i mean what are the methods to insert value in them? prompt boxes only display when I run the report in report wizard, if I called it from my application, there is no prompt box.

Comment: is there any other method than prompt box? can those parameters access values from our program like from textfield using textfield.getText?